# Circular Depepdency in Angular while using dynamic component loading

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, circular-dependency

I am in the process of building a generic component shared-library which can allow me to have nested-component in angular. 
eg: A card within a card / or a grid-within-a-grid or say a card-within-a-grid etc .
**In general its going to be a `ui-component` within a `ui-component`**

Since this are going to be dynamic components I have a `component-manager-service` written for it to get this components from the backend. 
It also uses a `component-manager-helper.service` to work out on the details of each `component` .
 
Hence here i have a kind of circular dependency where : 

**`component --> component-manager-service --> component` 
 
`component-->component-manager-service-->component-manager-helper.service-->component`**

Here I get the usual **`WARNING in Circular dependency detected:`** error.

Code Sample:
Component :

```
export class component {
    id: string;
    relationalElements: Map<string, Map<string, component>>;
    public getRelationalElements(str: string): Map<string, component> {
        return this.relationalElements.get(str);
    }
    public getId(): string {
        return this.id;
    }
    static fromJSON(json: componentIntf): component {
        let comp = Object.create(component.prototype);
        return Object.assign(comp, json, {
            relationalElements: ComponentMgrService.getMap(json.relationalElements),
            attributes: ComponentMgrService.getAttributesMap(json.attributes) //reference to component manager-service
        });
    }
}
```

Component-manager-service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentMgrService {
    constructor() { }
    public static getMap(json: any): Map<string, Map<string, component>> {
        let mprtyp = Object.create(Map.prototype);
        let mapobj = Object.assign(mprtyp, json);
        let data: any[] = json;
        let m: Map<string, Map<string, component>> = new Map<string, Map<string, component>>();// reference to component
        for (var i in data) {
            var item = data[i];
            m.set(i + "", this.getInnerMap(i, item));
        }
        return m
    }
}
```

Compoment-manager-helper-service

```
@Injectable()
export class CompMgrHlprService {

  constructor() { }
  public static getPele(i:string,json:any):component{
    if(i==="REL"){
      console.log("ComponentMgrService>json is:");
      console.log(json);

  return componentRel.fromJSON(json);//    m.set(i,ComponentMgrService.getPele(i,item));
  }else if(i==="FIELD") {

    return FormField.fromJSON(json);
  }else if(i==="COMP") {

    return component.fromJSON(json);
  }return null;
  }

}
```

How can i resolve t.

Comment: why does your service depends on you component. Could you provide code i'm not sure about your explanation.

Comment: @JEY i have edited the question with the code sample of the component and the related manager service.

Comment: Like i said this is not the code in error. You don't have any dependencies between those two elements.

Comment: I have put a comment "//reference to component manager-service" in the "component " class and a comment "// reference to component" in the ComponentMgrService where they reference each other in a way A-->B-->A which gives me a warning during compilation , however things work fine at runtime.  this is the warning i got `WARNING in Circular dependency detected: src/app/domain/component/component.ts -> src/app/service/component-mgr.service.ts -> src/app/domain/component/component.ts ` . Also added the code of 3rd class `CompMgrHlprService`in the main question

Comment: There are a lots of error in the given code. For instance this.getInnerMap in ComponentMgrService.getMap is wrong you try to access non static context from a static one.

Comment: @JEY I did the change for the ComponentMgrService to make a static call to getInnerMap (which is already a static method) `m.set(i+"",ComponentMgrService.getInnerMap(i,item));` however still it dosen't make any difference to the Circular-dependency issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce with the given code. Compilation finish without any error or warning.

Comment: @TarunPatel Did you have any luck?  I am thinking this isn't supported. 

If you are using a Service to construct components, a `Container` requires access to the Service.  When that container contains a container,  this new instance requires access to the service in an iterative fashion and  I get the same Circular Dependency.

Comment: @JEY You might not get any warnings if they are , since the circular-dependency related flag   in the angular-config json might have been disabled.

Comment: @user1059939 the above code still compiles and runs fine.